# Engraved text effect in android app

Tags: android

I want to have the in time famous Engraved text effect in my android app. I have searched for it but couldn't get any effective results. My code in XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/am"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Admissions"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"            
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>!["application"][1]
```

i just want to show "Admission" title in engraved form.. tell  me color combination other wise that which color shadow i have to use..

here is the link http://goo.gl/6grsZ

Answer (score 8):

Try out this one.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/Grey"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Engraved Shadow"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:shadowColor="@color/White"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="0.6" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Refer from [here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/378).

Comment: Broken link at bottom!

Comment: To get this emboss to work, I had to add:    android:layerType="software"   to the above TextView